# Add data from table two relative to table one

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I need to display a table that shows the user that in-putted the joke into the database. I have a table for the jokes names 'joke' and a table for the user named 'author'
joke table has id, joketext, jokedate, authorid
author table has id, name, email
so the 'authorid' is the same as the 'id' in author table.

```
<?php
$con=mysqli_connect("localhost","user","password","ijdb");
// Check connection
if (mysqli_connect_errno())
  {
  echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
  }

$result = mysql_query("SELECT joke.id, joketext, name, email FROM joke INNER JOIN author
ON authorid = author.id");

echo "<form action='delete1.php' method='post'>
<table border='1'>
<tr>
<th>Joke</th>
<th>Date</th>
<th>Name</th>
<th>Email</th>
<th>Delete</th>
</tr>";

while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
  {
  echo "<tr>";
  echo "<td>" . $row['joketext'] . "</td>";
  echo "<td>" . $row['jokedate'] . "</td>";
  echo "<td>" . $row['name'] . "</td>";
  echo "<td>" . $row['email'] . "</td>";
  echo "<td><input type='submit' name='deleteItem' value='".$row['id']."' /></td>";
  echo "</tr>";
  }
  echo "</table>";

  echo "</form></br>";

mysqli_close($con);
?>
```

I get this error
Warning: mysqli_fetch_array() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result, boolean given in C:\xampp\htdocs\kimmy\jokes\joke1.php on line 22
and an empty table

Thanks

Comment: If you're using `mysqli`, you have to use `mysqli_query()`, not `mysql_query()`.

Comment: add `.die(mysql_error());` where query is executing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It should be:

```
$result = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT joke.id, joketext, name, email FROM joke INNER JOIN author
                              ON authorid = author.id");
```

You can't use `mysql_query()` when you're using the `mysqli` extension.

Answer (score 2):

Error is you are using 
    mysql_query
instead of
    mysqli_query

so the code becomes

```
<?php
$con=mysqli_connect("localhost","user","password","ijdb");
// Check connection
if (mysqli_connect_errno())
  {
  echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
  }

$result = mysqli_query("SELECT joke.id, joketext, name, email FROM joke INNER JOIN author
ON authorid = author.id");

echo "<form action='delete1.php' method='post'>
<table border='1'>
<tr>
<th>Joke</th>
<th>Date</th>
<th>Name</th>
<th>Email</th>
<th>Delete</th>
</tr>";

while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
  {
  echo "<tr>";
  echo "<td>" . $row['joketext'] . "</td>";
  echo "<td>" . $row['jokedate'] . "</td>";
  echo "<td>" . $row['name'] . "</td>";
  echo "<td>" . $row['email'] . "</td>";
  echo "<td><input type='submit' name='deleteItem' value='".$row['id']."' /></td>";
  echo "</tr>";
  }
  echo "</table>";

  echo "</form></br>";

mysqli_close($con);
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try changing the following

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT joke.id, joketext, name, email FROM joke INNER JOIN author
```

ON authorid = author.id");

to

```
$result = mysqli_query("SELECT joke.id, joketext, name, email FROM joke INNER JOIN author
```

ON authorid = author.id");

You are using mysql_query instead of mysqli_query